# Disable Right Click on Images only

Tags: image, copyright

There are some Image I don't want to allow 'Save as this image' using right click

How can I make disable Right Click on Product Images Only?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about magento.

Comment: Wait, why would you only want product images disabled and not the other arbitrary images on your site? Why not all images?

Comment: You're right I need for all Image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use Javascript to accomplish this.

Take a look at [How do I disable right click on my web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page)

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){
    if (e.target.nodeName === "IMG") {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

Please Note: No matter what you do, you can't prevent users from having full access to every bit of data on your website and can be easily disable by a knowledgeable user.